# Is it safe to link compiled object files from different GCC versions?

Tags: gcc, compilation

Is it safe to link objects generated from sources compiled with different GCC versions into a shared library?

I assume not, but in case the used GCCs have no difference in regards to code generation and optimization improvement? Is there an information to know which GCC compiler is not backward compatible?

My question is also concerns the binaries, I looked in

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html

From my understanding, different GCC version would be compatible as long as they Conform to the same ABI

Comment: How different are the versions of GCC?  If you're trying to link code from GCC 2.x with GCC 6.x, there's a chance there'll be problems.  If you're mixing 4.9.4 with 4.9.3, there won't be a problem.  I've not encountered problems with 4.x or 5.x code mixed with 6.x code, but that's no guarantee that you can't find problems.  OTOH, the ABI (application binary interface) for a platform is usually stable over periods of years, and all sorts of different compilers work with it, so I'd be surprised if there was a problem (even with 2.x and 6.x being mixed — provided that the object file type is OK).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler From 4.4 to 4.7? I did not find any problem while testing, but I am not sure how covering my testing is since I am not sure of what are `the possible problems that can occur`

Comment: In my view, partly based on experience, it is unlikely you're going to run into any issues.  I'm not sure I can quote documentation that supports that contention — which is a main reason I've not jumped in with an answer instead of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After doing a research on the web, and reading several GCC release notes, it seems that GCC is backward compatible if there is no ABI change.
In general, this would be stated in the release notes.

I also did some experiment using different GCC compilers and GCC linkers (by different meaning from different versions of GCC) and I got linker errors when it was incompatible (different ABI versions).

Comment: I had a similar issue and did some internet research too. All recent GCC versions on my system seam to create objects file in linux ELF format. I was wondering if that basically means they are compatible across versions, since ELF is a formal format definition. However, I’m neigther an expert with the ABI nor with ELF topic, but I assume even producing the same (ELF) format this doesn’t necessarily mean they use the same ABI.